# How to find the password for the embedded weblogic server of jdeveloper please?

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper, weblogic11g

How to find the password for the embedded  weblogic server of jdeveloper please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define the password the first time you start the embedded WLS - assuming you are on a recent JDev version. If you don't remember what you specified then delete the defaultDomain directory in the systemxxx directory and relaunch JDev.

If you are on an old JDev it is likely weblogic1